# data visualization from timestream using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sdk, pysimplegui, amazon-timestream

I have a AWS Timestream database and i want to visualize the data in the timestream database on a graph (temperature & humidity) using python. I am planninig to use PySimpleGUI for data visualization. I really need to know the process to extract my data from AWS timestream DB so that i can implement a GUI using this real-time data.
Any alternate solution would work,

Thank you,

I am searching a way to extract data from AWS timestream and meanwhile visualize on the GUI using python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JDBC driver to pull data from AWS Timestream as described in [AWS Timestream Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/JDBC.html) Queries are described in [AWS Timestream Query Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/reference.html)

It may be easier if you use [AWS Timestream Python Query SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.query-client.html)